# What is an AWS CodeStar SyncResource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, pipelining

I used CodeStar to create a DataPipeline that:

1. Downloads code from my github repo
2. Tests it in CodeBuild,
3. Creates/executes a CloudFormation changeset on a CloudFormation  stack that CodeStar created
4. Which creates/updates a lambda.

The CloudFormation Stack template references CodeStar::SyncResources. I also noticed the lambda function it created is actually part of a "Lambda Application". the Application has 2 resources: The lambda, and the "SyncResources"

The Cloudformation ChangeSet uses this and I notice that when I push a commit where the function's code isn't changed (for example, when I change the README), the SyncResources gets passed in the ChangeSet execution, but not the lambda itself. If I comment the changeset out in the template than the lambda gets updated everytime even if it isn't changed.

what the heck is this thing? Couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: Interesting, [no official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation&searchQuery=SyncResources "Your search for "SyncResources" returned no results.") indeed. And people [ask](https://hackernoon.com/welcome-to-cloud-native-development-with-aws-cloud9-aws-codestar-c7b6536afba8 "Welcome to Cloud-Native Development with AWS Cloud9 & AWS CodeStar") themselves the same question. Others [seem to be able to use it](https://github.com/kmamykin/react-aws/blob/master/cfn-static-site-pipeline.yml#L369 "react-aws/cfn-static-site-pipeline.yml") anyway though.